# Colouring faces of a graph according to an overlap of edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting

I have a basic graph such as the following;

```
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

which produces;

[image: graph]

What I would like to do is to colour the triangle without edge overlaps one colour, say red, and the other triangles with edge overlaps another colour, say green. I have done a fair bit of searching on here, but can't quite find anything that will help me with this issue. If there is something on here, I apologise.

Edit: I haven't made clear what exactly it I want, so I'll try here.

Above is a connected graph that I would like to colour according to certain criteria. The colouring is due to the idea of how many triangles we have. As per the diagram above, I would like to colour {3, 6, 2} red, and since triangles {1, 3, 4} and {1, 3, 2} join together to form a quadrilateral, I would like to colour this entire region {1, 3, 2, 4} green.

Of course I would like to apply this to larger images, but to understand how to colour these faces with these different colours is a starting point for me that I would like to attempt to develop by myself. I hope this is a little clearer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)

The above link and its image I hope makes clear the idea behind what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the triangle with edge overlaps". It's also unclear to me if you are talking about the graph, or a specific drawing of the graph. Please clarify. It would be best if you could show the desired output.

Comment: So the triangles with edge overlaps would be {1, 3, 2} and {1, 2, 4} which would encompass the region {1, 3, 2, 4}. So, I don't have an exact copy of the above image with colours, but something similar, in which the region {1, 3, 2, 4} would be coloured dark blue as per the attached diagram and {3, 6, 2} would be coloured light blue as per the attached. 

![link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)#/media/File:VR_complex.svg)

Comment: Please make the question self-contained: include all information in the question instead of comments. It's still not clear to me what the output should be, and why. Based on what principle do you identify 1,3,2 and 1,2,4 as "triangles with edge overlaps", and why only these? In the original question you talked only about triangles, but now you ask about colouring 1,3,2,4, which is just one of the many 4-cycles in this graph. Is your question specific to this one instance, or are you trying to achieve implement something for any graph (and if yes, what)?

Comment: You can use `Polygon` to create a polygon. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphicsAndSound.html) for constructing graphics. Use the graph's vertex coordinates as the coordinates of polygon vertices. You can extract them with `GraphEmbedding`. This way you can manually fill out the structures you mentioned.

Comment: Are you asking only about drawing or are you asking if MMA can recognize where an overlap is. Note that there are trivial overlaps that can be eliminated by regrouping the vertices.   Recognizing non trivial overlaps is not easy. But if you deliver information which triangle to draw in which color that is easy.

Comment: Hi Daniel, initally I was simply colouring faces according to hardcoded input, but yes, as you say, I am now attempting to see if I can get the overlaps to be determined. If you have an idea of where I can look in the documentation, it will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't quite understand how you want to decide what to fill out, here's a function that can fill in cycles that you specify manually.

This solves the styling issue only, not the issue of selecting cycles to fill.

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, GrayLevel[0, 1]]]

fillCycles[graph_?GraphQ, spec : {___Style}] := 
 Module[{indexAsc = AssociationThread[VertexList[g] -> Range@VertexCount[g]], 
   nameToIndex},
  SetAttributes[nameToIndex, Listable];
  nameToIndex[name_] := indexAsc[name];
  Graph[graph, 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[0.5], 
     GraphicsComplex[GraphEmbedding[graph], 
      MapAt[Polygon@*nameToIndex, spec, {All, 1}]]}]]

fillCycles[g, {Style[{{1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4}}, Green], 
  Style[{4, 3, 6, 2}, Blue]}]
```

[image]

This function is not very robust—it's just a starting point.

The fill specification is expected be a list of the form `{Stle[{v1, v2, ..., vk}, color], ...}`

Comment: ok! This is great. Is there a way in which to colour multiple triangles the same colour by which we only specify the colour once? As an example, if I wanted to colour the triangles {1, 3, 2} and {1, 2, 4} green. I have tried several permutations of this but with no luck. An example of what I have tried is: {Style[{{1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4}}, Green]}. However this gives me no joy. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Keebles The code I showed is a starting point. I recommend that you understand it and modify it for your needs. I will quickly update the answer to support the syntax that you said you tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[addBlobs]
addBlobs[g_Graph, s_: .1, opacity_: .5] := {Opacity @ opacity, #, 
   MeshPrimitives[
      BoundingRegion[
        Join @@ (CirclePoints[#, s, 20] & /@ 
           (PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ #2)), 
        "MinConvexPolygon"], 
      2]} & @@@ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
    1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, ImageSize -> 360, 
   ImagePadding -> 20, VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> White, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> 12, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]];

polygons = {{Green, {1, 2, 3}}, {Blue, {2, 1, 4}}, {Red, {2, 3, 6}}};

Row[Flatten @ {g, 
   SetProperty[g, Prolog -> #[polygons]] & /@ {addBlobs[g, 0], addBlobs[g]}}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]

g2 = RandomGraph[{10, 15}, ImageSize -> 360, 
     ImagePadding -> 20, VertexSize -> .33, VertexStyle -> White,
     VertexLabelStyle -> 9, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]];

polygons =  Transpose[{ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[4], 
    VertexList /@ RandomSample[FindCycle[g2, {3, 4}, All], 5]}];

Row[Flatten @ {g2, 
   SetProperty[g2, Prolog -> #[polygons]] & /@ {addBlobs[g2, 0], addBlobs[g2]}}]
```

[image]